# Bulk user import in Django

Tags: python, django, python-import, bulk-import

I like to bulk import users from `xlsx` or `csv` to my original User model. I don't use `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` and I don't like to because my site is working and I don't want to abuse my schema.

I am using the original User model where I add the users (no user registration allowed) and I store the extra fields in my Profile model with a `OneToOne` relation.

I'm not so experienced so I tried to use code snippets that I found but I am still not able to achieve my goal. If I try to use `import-export` module in my admin panel it works with other models but not with the User model. `Tablib` or other solutions would be also interesting to me.

**models.py**
(I'm using the original User model that sends a signal to Profile model when a user is created)

```
class Profile(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)

user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, blank=True)
projekt = models.ForeignKey(Projekt, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)   

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I got this error message:

```
django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model User is already registered with 'auth.UserAdmin'.
```

I understand that my User model is in use but what could I do?

Comment: it seems like UserAdmin already registered somewhere else, probably in the library code. maybe try extending it with `from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
  class UserAdmin(ImportExportMixin, UserAdmin):` instead . Also check your other admin files if there already unregistered, registered User model

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The User model is registered in the auth app but the UserAdmin is not.